# How to clear cache in Linux without flooding dmesg?

Tags: shell, cache, dmesg

I have a shell script which repeatedly clears the cache with

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The trouble is that this ends up completely flooding dmesg because it runs so often.

Is there a way to do this while suppressing the resulting kernel messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you echo 4 to `drop_caches` first, subsequent `drop_caches` messages won’t be generated:

```
echo 4 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The setting is sticky and will remain until the system is rebooted.

See the last paragraph of [the kernel documentation for `drop_caches`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#drop-caches). Note also that, as explained in that documentation, dropping caches isn’t a good idea, and shouldn’t be done repeatedly; see also [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5509a5d27b971a90b940e148ca9ca53312e4fa7a).